# default form is not shown

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I added a custom form to my opportunity entity so now I have the default "Information" form and now my new custom form.

I have changed the order using the "form order" dialog to change my custom form from top to bottom.

No matter how I rearange this, the new custom form shows by default.

What is causing this and how can I change it?

**UPDATE:**
I have discovered that the forms are showing in the correct order BUT once a form is selected it becomes the default view on a per user basis.

So any user that has not used that entity before will have the default form. Once they switch the other one now becomes default for that user only.

I would just like to hide the other form in the dropdown list, which I will attempt to do with JS.

Comment: try posting some of the code that you have thus far so that we can see.. it would be nice what you have tried..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks for the reply. You can recreate this without any code, just create a new form and try to make it default or not default by using the "form order" dialog.

Comment: I got cha.. I wonder if forms are being initialized or created out of order based on where you have the initialzie componets call.. I might be thinking Delphi here..but the same concept should apply to C#

Comment: Have you specified any individual roles to the forms?

Comment: @glosrob I have not, but have also tried to set both forms to "Display to everyone"

Comment: What you are doing seems to be correct, so perhaps the form order is not being applied. my only thought is to ensure that you publish and refresh the form after you set form order.

Comment: @LukeBaulch Do you know off-hand which table stores this info so I can verify? Thanks!

Comment: @JonC: No, not sure which table. I think the correct way to hide forms is to use security roles, but you may need to use JS if this method doesn't suit your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the forms are showing in the correct order BUT once a form is selected it becomes the default view on a per user basis.

So any user that has not used that entity before will have the default form. Once they switch the other one now becomes default for that user only.